Deprecation of third party cookies in Google Chrome and Cookie bot
hope you're having a good day, i'll cut to the chase.
I'm using cookiebot and gtg for my websites and since Google is introducing Privacy Sandbox
https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/cookies/prepare/overview
I'm a bit confused of how this will affect my sites. I read this article from Cookie bot ( which is pretty much a copy paste from the first link)
But all i see is they're hoping Google will push privacy sandbox back again
https://www.cookiebot.com/en/google-third-party-cookies/
Is there a way to know which changes i will have to do in order to still use Cookie bot or should i start looking for alternatives ?
Thank you for your time

Cookiebot is a CMP. Why would it depend on Google's privacy sandbox?
